# Accessors not working on Backpack v5 select2 field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

Working on a Invoice Generator admin panel for myself and i stumbled on another problem with the accessor. I have found and tried various tutorials for Laravel 8 and Laravel 9, but they all seem to go to the same result.

A company can have multiple bank accounts setup, but when I generate the invoice, I would like for the user to select one bank account to be shown on the invoice. For this I want to show the bank account in a select2 in the format of Bank Account Name(Sort code-Account number).

**InvoiceCrudController.php**

```
CRUD::addField([
        'name'      =>  'companies_bank_account_id',
        'type'      =>  'select2',
        'label'     =>  'Bank account',
        'tab'       =>  'Payment',
        'entity'    =>  'bank_account',
        'attribute' =>  'companies_bank_account_name',
        'model'     =>  '\App\Models\CompaniesBankAccount',
        'wrapper'   =>  [ 'class' => 'form-group col-md-4' ],
    ]);
```

**Invoice.php** Model

```
public function getCompaniesBankAccountNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->companies_bank_account_name . '(' . $this->companies_bank_account_sort_code . '/' . $this->companies_bank_account_number . ')';
}
```

**Company.php** Model

```
public function bank_accounts() {
    return $this->hasMany(CompaniesBankAccount::class, 'company_id');
}
```

**CompaniesBankAccount.php** Model

```
public function company() {
    return $this->BelongsToOne(\App\Models\Company::class, 'company_id');
}
```

So, adding the bank accounts for the company works just fine, but I cannot show multiple attributes to the user using an accessor.

***Bank Accounts added to the Company***

[image: Bank Accounts added to the Company]

***End result when adding an invoice***

[image: End result when adding an invoice]

If possible to help me spot my mistake or point me to a tutorial, would really appreciate it.

Thanks,
George

Comment: Looks good to me! I would suggest using `php artisan tinker` or something like that to debug if the accessor doesn't have a typo or anything.